# Problem laying out items in an image gallery

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having trouble laying out my items in a gallery.  I would like to be able to display an image in a horizontal or vertical format and have it fit within a fixed 300px x 300px box and align to the bottom of the box.  I would like the "attribution" to line up with the right edge of the image.  Here is a picture of the desired layout.
[Picture of desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LkVo.png)

This is the html:

```css
.gallery {
  display:flex;
  gap: 10px;
  }
.gallery_item_square {
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  background: brown;
}

.gallery_square {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  background: green;
}

.gallery_description {
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
}

.image_attribution {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:flex-end;

}

.image_square {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
    display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:flex-end;

}

.gallery_attribution {
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
}

.image {

  height:100%;
  background: green;
  width:
}

.image_contain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:contain;
  object-position: bottom;
}

.attribution {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery_item_square">
      <div class="gallery_square">
        <div class="image_attribution">
          <div class="image_square">
            <div class="image">
              <img class="image_contain" src="https://acrossky.github.io/Images/3W6A8814.jpg">
                <span class="attribution"> <a href="source">ARC/Qedema</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
       
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery_description">
        <p>This is a description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item_square">
      <div class="gallery_square">
        <div class="image_attribution">
          <div class="image_square">
            <div class="image">
              <img class="image_contain" src="https://acrossky.github.io/Images/3W6A8817.jpg">
                <span class="attribution"> <a href="source">ARC/Qedema</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery_description">
        <p>This is a description</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am unable to make the image fit within the box.  Ive tried use "object-fit:contain" but to no avail.  I would be grateful for any help you can offer.

---

Update: the code is almost working.  The last item is to make the attribution align with edge of the image. [align attribution to edge of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckbYK.jpg)  Here is the latest version of the code in Codepen.
https://codepen.io/acrossky/pen/KKoNdPX

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.gallery_item_square {
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  background: brown;
}

.gallery_square {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: green;
}

.gallery_description {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image_attribution {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.image_square {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;

}

.gallery_attribution {
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.image_contain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: bottom;
}

.attribution {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery_item_square">
    <div class="gallery_square">
      <div class="image_attribution">
        <div class="image_square">
          <div class="image">
            <img class="image_contain" src="https://acrossky.github.io/Images/3W6A8814.jpg">
            <span class="attribution"> <a href="source">ARC/Qedema</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_description">
      <p>This is a description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_item_square">
    <div class="gallery_square">
      <div class="image_attribution">
        <div class="image_square">
          <div class="image">
            <img class="image_contain" src="https://acrossky.github.io/Images/3W6A8817.jpg">
            <span class="attribution"> <a href="source">ARC/Qedema</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_description">
      <p>This is a description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I took your code and added  '.object-fit: contain' to the image.  It is pretty close.  I just need to make the image align to the bottom of the container.  Here is the code: https://codepen.io/acrossky/pen/KKoNdPX

Comment: @ACross please check out the updated snipped above. By using `object-position: bottom;` you can align the image to the bottom of the container

Comment: Thanks SharPei.  That worked!  I was trying to do that with flex-end... but cleary the wrong tool for the job.  The final edit I would like to make to the code is to make the attribution align to the edge of the image. I will upload an image to illustrate.  I updated the code on codepen: https://codepen.io/acrossky/pen/KKoNdPX.

Comment: @ACross simply changing your `.attribution` span to `display: block` will fix the immediate problem. If you want to align the text on the right side you can add `text-align: right;`. Check out the updated snippet above and if all your questions are covered please accept the answer

Comment: The attribution text doesn't align with the edge of the vertical image.  It aligns with the edge of the container, which works fine for horizontal images but doesn't look that great with vertical images.